# Prove $a^2+b^2+c^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ given that $a^2+x^2=b^2+y^2=c^2+z^2=(a+b)^2+(x+y)^2=(b+c)^2+(y+z)^2=(c+a)^2+(z+x)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

Prove $$a^2+b^2+c^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$$ given that $$a^2+x^2=b^2+y^2=c^2+z^2=\\(a+b)^2+(x+y)^2=(b+c)^2+(y+z)^2=(c+a)^2+(z+x)^2$$ where $a,b,c,x,y,z \in\mathbb R$

A friend forwarded me this problem which recently appeared in a math contest at Costa Rica. I've been working on it but I can't find a definite proof, though I have discovered several facts:

> Let $u$ be equal to the value of the equation, then $ab+xy=\frac{-u}{2}$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=3u$ which implies that $(a+b+c)^2+(x+y+z)^2 = 0 \implies a+b+c=x+y+z=0$.

> I also noticed that, because of the equalities, working with complex numbers or vectors would be really tempting, as if $r=a+ix$, $s=b+iy$, $t=c+iz$, then we have $|r|=|s|=|t|=|r+s|=|s+t|=|r+t|$, but I can't find a way to make it useful.

Any ideas/hints/solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second observation is astute! Simply for interest, I would make one further observation, which is that the question geometrically asks us to prove

> Given three $2D$ vectors (equivalently, complex numbers $r,s,t$) with given equality of lengths, prove the two $3D$ vectors $$\mathbf{u}=(a \quad b \quad c) , \qquad \mathbf{v}=(x \quad y \quad z)$$ are also of equal length (see the paper linked below for the condition that three vectors in the plane are images under orthogonal projection of an orthornormal basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

As others have pointed out, since $$|r|=|s|=|t|=|r+s|=|s+t|=|t+r|,$$ then, by *the parallelogram law of addition*, $r,s,t$ form an equilateral triangle, with centre of mass on the origin, in $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$. We know the cube roots of unity $$1,\quad \omega=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \quad \omega^2=-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ form an equilateral triangle in $\mathbb{C}$. We know also that there exists a complex number $\alpha$ such that the transformation $$z\mapsto \alpha z$$ maps $\triangle rst$ onto $\triangle 1\omega \omega^2$. Under this transformation, the lengths of $r,s,t$ are all scaled by some real number $R$. Since, as you can check for yourself, the result holds in this special case, and since rotation is an *isometry* (distance preserving map), we see that $$R|\mathbf{u}|=R|\mathbf{v}|$$ and so the result holds in general. $\square$

**Alternatively**, for a more purely complex algebraic proof note that, taking $r,s,t$ as points on a circle centred at the origin, $$\tag{1}\triangle rst\space \mathrm{is \space equilateral} \iff \begin{cases} r+s+t=0\\r^2+s^2+t^2=rs+st+tr\end{cases}$$ Equating the real parts of each equation in $(1)$ gives $$\tag{2}a+b+c=0\implies ab+bc+ca=-\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$ and $$a^2+b^2+c^2-(x^2+y^2+z^2)=ab+bc+ca-(xy+yz+zx)\tag{3}.$$ Since $(2)$ also holds for imaginary parts, we conclude $$a^2+b^2+c^2=x^2+y^2+z^2\tag{4}.\quad \square$$ This path to the result is perhaps the cleanest, but, as presented, it offers less clue as to *why* the symmetry occurs. The proofs of the equations in $(1)$, however, recover some of this why and point to a wider theory of [orthogonal projections](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001097). Both equations can also in fact be deduced from rotations of the plane, which is a good exercise.

Answer (score 5):

You are very close. Both your approaches point to the fact that $r$, $s$, $t$ form an equilateral triangle (three points on a circle, with center of mass at the origin). Then, if you use the exponential notation, the points are at $Re^{i\phi}$, $Re^{i\phi+2\pi/3}$, $Re^{i\phi+4\pi/3}$. Then it's easy to show that $$\sin^2\phi+\sin^2\left(\phi+\frac{2\pi}3\right)+\sin^2\left(\phi+\frac{4\pi}3\right)=\cos^2\phi+\cos^2\left(\phi+\frac{2\pi}3\right)+\cos^2\left(\phi+\frac{4\pi}3\right)=\frac32$$
Multiply with $R$ and you get your desired result.

Comment: How did you prove that $r,s,t$ form an equilateral triangle?

Comment: Since all three points are at the same distance from the origin, the origin is the circumcenter of the triangle. Since the center of mass is at the origin (as shown in the hint), it means that the perpendicular bisectors on the sides are also medians. So the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: Yes, I see now.

Comment: Another way that uses just the complex number interpretation, from $ |r| = |s| = |r+s|$, show that $r, s$ are $120^\circ$ apart, and hence $r, s, t$ form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand.